# OpsHub reported a time out exception while migrating work items from TFS to VSO

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Generally, OpsHub works quite good. But when the migration destination is a VSO instance of which the user number is very large, e.g., thousands or tens of thousands, OpsHub will stay at the User Mapping step for a long time (about 2 miniutes) and finally it reported a time out exception, as below:
[image: time out issue]

I tried to modify the time out paramters in .config files but it didn't help. Did I configure in a wrong way? Or is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Increase your TFS Server Time-out time. For the steps, refer to this blog from MSDN for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ablock/archive/2008/09/16/increasing-the-time-out-time.aspx

Comment: Hi, could you please send us the logs from "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs" , the version of the migration utility and total number of users in your VSO account on support@opshub.com